# Is there a function to stretch an image's points to parts of the renderer in SDL2?

Tags: c, sdl-2

Is there a function to stretch an image's points to coordinates on the screen based on it's four points?

If not, is there a way I could do that using math?

Comment: To clarify, I mean something like a generalized texture-mapped quad.

Comment: Why don't you use OpenGL? Also, I think you should add your clarification in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I mean something like a generalized texture-mapped quad.

[`SDL_RenderGeometry()`/`SDL_RenderGeometryRaw()`](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/release-2.0.18/include/SDL_render.h#L1601-L1651) were added in [SDL 2.0.18](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/releases/tag/release-2.0.18).